# Finding int in file with tab, c programming

Tags: c, file, tabs, int

I have a small problem, I need to find 3 integers in file, looking like this:

```
some variable text size here \t int \t int \t n  (just tabs no space)

some variable text size here1 \t int \t int \t n  (just tabs no space)
```

My problem is how to find int in variable text size, my firs idea is with `fscanf`:

```c
 fscanf (file, "%d\t%d\t%d",&firs,&second,&third)
```

However that doesn't work or to read whole line in char buffer and then somehow to find tab and then after tab to extract int.
Please some help.

Comment: Read it line by line and split each line by tabs.

Comment: One way is to use `fgets()` and then `strtok()` on the string read, and IMO, easier and cleaner than struggling with `fscanf()` formats.

Comment: could there be any tabs in `some variable text size here`?

Comment: No tabs in text, just one before int and between int

Comment: why not giving a sample of the file ?

Comment: What is the dangling `n` at the end mean?

Comment: @TestAndSet Is `n` means a newline?

Comment: Sorry, it means int and than new line

Comment: your example has 2 `int`, not 3 `int`.

Comment: My mistake, but not so important,
@iharob gave very nice solution and pretty short.
I didn't expected that that problem is more than two lines of code, I guess I was wrong, thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int integers[2];

while (fscanf (file, "%*[^\t]%d%d%*[^\n]", &integers[0], &integers[1]) == 2)
    printf("%d, %d\n", integers[0], integers[1]);
```

`"%*[^\t]"` means capture any character except `"\t"` and don't store the value `'*'`, and I suppose you understand `"%*[^\n]"`, and the `"%d"` specifier ignores leading spaces anyway so you don't need to specify the  leading `"\t"`, but you do need to specify two `"%d"` specifiers.

Comment: `"*[^\t\n]"` does not contribute much to properly scanning the line.

Comment: @chux As always this is one of my attempts to understand the `scanf()` family, can you please explain?

Comment: `scanf()` returns 2 even if nothing follows the 2nd `int`.  It _does_ affect the success of the next line.  All-in-all. line oriented data should be read a line at a time.

Comment: I also thought of that, it will return then number of arguments matched, so if it matches 2 integers then it continues to the next possible match regarless of whatever characters are there if they match the first specifier, am I right?

Comment: No.  If the following `"*[^\t\n]"` does not exist, scanning just stops.  The next `fscanf()` picks up where things left off.  The major issue is that OP has explained what to look for but is fuzzy on what is bad.  If you were specifying this, certainly you would not allow `'\n'` to be consumed by `"%d"` like this answer does.  IMO: user input is evil and unless it matches exactly the spec, it should be declared errant input.   Your format will scan good input, but passes lots of bad input.

Comment: Thank you all, solved by @iharob solution, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int char1(const char **p, char ch){
    if(**p == ch){
        ++*p;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static inline int tab(const char **p){
    return char1(p, '\t');
}
static inline int hyphen(const char **p){
    return char1(p, '-');
}
int repeat1(const char **p, int (*test)(int)){
    //test : test character type (e.g isdigit)
    //[character kind]+
    const char *tmp = *p;
    while(test(**p))
        ++*p;
    return *p != tmp;
}
int repeatpn(const char **p, int (*parser)(const char **), int n){
    const char *tmp = *p;
    if(n<1) return 0;
    while(n && parser(p))
        --n;
    if(n != 0){
        *p = tmp;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
static inline int digits(const char **p){
    return repeat1(p, isdigit);
}
static inline int natural(const char **p){
    return digits(p);//Alias, allow start 0 (e.g 012)
}
int negative_integer(const char **p){
    const char *tmp = *p;
    if(hyphen(p) && natural(p))
        return 1;
    *p = tmp;
    return 0;
}
static inline int integer(const char **p){
    //note : does not mean the range of int
    return natural(p) || negative_integer(p);
}
int tabAndInteger(const char **p){
    const char *tmp = *p;
    if(tab(p) && integer(p))
        return 1;
    *p = tmp;
    return 0;
}
int my_match(const char **p){
    //(\t\d+){3}
    return repeatpn(p, tabAndInteger, 3);
}

int main(void){
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char text[256];
    int v1, v2, v3;
    while(fgets(text, sizeof text, file)){
        const char *p = strchr(text, '\t'), *tmp = p;
        if(my_match(&tmp)){//\t\d+\t\d+\t\d+
            sscanf(p, "%d%d%d", &v1,&v2,&v3);
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", v1, v2, v3);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```